# Command 'makemessages' error

Tags: django

I newbe in django and python. My project created under PyTools for Visual Studio 2013.
For localization I create 'locale' folder on manage.py level. And I try run the following command:

.\ClarisPyEnv\Scripts\python.exe manage.py makemessages -l he

And I got the error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2377:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 921, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 869, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1170, in _readerthread
    buffer.append(fh.read())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1255.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 766: char
acter maps to <undefined>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Documents\PythonProjects\ClarisPy\ClarisPy\ClarisPyEnv\lib
\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_co
mmand_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Documents\PythonProjects\ClarisPy\ClarisPy\ClarisPyEnv\lib
\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Documents\PythonProjects\ClarisPy\ClarisPy\ClarisPyEnv\lib
\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Documents\PythonProjects\ClarisPy\ClarisPy\ClarisPyEnv\lib
\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Documents\PythonProjects\ClarisPy\ClarisPy\ClarisPyEnv\lib
\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 533, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Documents\PythonProjects\ClarisPy\ClarisPy\ClarisPyEnv\lib
\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemessages.py", line 290, in ha
ndle_noargs
    self.write_po_file(potfile, locale)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Documents\PythonProjects\ClarisPy\ClarisPy\ClarisPyEnv\lib
\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemessages.py", line 402, in wr
ite_po_file
    msgs, errors, status = popen_wrapper(args)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Documents\PythonProjects\ClarisPy\ClarisPy\ClarisPyEnv\lib
\site-packages\django\core\management\utils.py", line 25, in popen_wrapper
    output, errors = p.communicate()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 959, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1234, in _communicate
    stdout = stdout[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What this means ? Where a problem? help me please!

Thank
Alex

Comment: I think it is a decoding problem, did you write your test like this ? _(u"you text here"), '_' being 'ugettext as _', the u is for Unicode text.

Comment: In my views.py file a wrote 
        context_instance = RequestContext(request,
        {
            'title':_(u'Home Page'),
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        })
Where I can write test? Please explain.

Comment: And I  don't understand - where the error? In which file?

Comment: All of your text should be warped in this expression ` _(u"you text here"),` also add `import ugettext as _` then run the command again

Comment: But if I have on views.py text _(u"some text") and "another text" and want tot translate only first. What happening ?

Comment: You need first to provide the text in a chosen language, then you collect the messages and translate the files generated. But first you need a text to translate, I usually go with English. All of the text you want to be translated should be like this: _(u"some text").

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to specify unicode in pyhton 3.
Unicode is default.

`from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _`

`_('חתול')`

Is enof for the translation and encoding to work.

Comment: From what i can see:
 `File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1234, in _communicate
    stdout = stdout[0]` 
is trying to print out to terminal? and most terminals dont support unicode encoding. by default settings

Comment: Why terminal? I try to generate django.po file for my project. I start the command .\ClarisPyEnv\Scripts\python.exe manage.py makemessages -l he from terminal windows. And I must get file django.po in .\locale\he\LC_MESSAGES directory. But I got the error.

Comment: Just googled this error found this:   https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15774
It seems like the error messages comes when your using none ASCII-characters in template comments.But newer versions of django should not have this error. What version do you use?

Comment: I've seen this ticket. I use 1.7.1 version. I already checked the templates for non ASCII characters and not found anything.